# Auto Deploy after push to git

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, cicd

I have some Codeigniter projects on some domains (on the same server), and the project is already in git.

How to ensure server gets the new update when I push the code to git?

Can anyone explain to me step by step?

Comment: What CI tool are you using?Please mention the all the tools you are using and if you are open to using other tools or not

Comment: Gitlab has the pipeline triggers. You could send a curl request to Jenkins to trigger a job there or Gitlab itself can deploy data with rsync or whatever you want. Both is done with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file see here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Git and Jenkins job. Create a Jenkins Job to deploy your code to server and Setup Git webhook to Call Jenkins job.

Check this link: https://www.serverkaka.com/2019/02/configure-github-webhook-in-jenkins-job-pipeline.html

> OR

1. Create an empty Git repo on the server
2. Write a Git Hook to deploy the code
3. Deploy from the local computer

Check this link: https://medium.com/@francoisromain/vps-deploy-with-git-fea605f1303b

Answer (score 0):

Depens on how you hosting your application in production

1. If non docker: use [capistrano](https://capistranorb.com) or other symlink deployment tool
2. If docker: use `docker swarm deploy` to update your containers
3. Then you need just add [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/#creating-a-gitlab-ciyml-file) file to your project directory and write some deployment scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Git itself has a server-side [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). You can use it to run a command that triggers your deployment whenever you push to your repo. Web services like Gitlab or Bitbucket rely on this mechanism to offer plug-ins that trigger CI services. Less flexible but you can configure it conveniently from the web front end.

---

Another option would be to use a tool like Puppet on the target machine that periodically checks the repo for changes and pulls them in. The following Puppet code would clone/update the repo into the `/path/to/repo` directory (by default Puppet runs every 30 min):

```
vcsrepo { '/path/to/repo':
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git://example.com/repo.git',
}
```

See the [documentation of the vcsrepo module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) for details.